# Linear Algebra and Fredholm's Alternative Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=$ $ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -3 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & -1 \\
3 & -2 & 1 \end{array} \right]$

(a) Determine the value of $\beta$ such that $Ax=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
4\\
1\\
\beta\end{array}\right]$ has solutions, and identify all solutions.

(b) Show that for all solutions $x$ and $w\in \ker(A^{T})$, $x\cdot w\ne0$ (This is known as Fredholm's Alternative).

I have finished (a) and $\ker(A^{T})$, $x=k\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1/7\\
5/7\\
1\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1\\
-1\\
0\end{array}\right]$,
$w=\text{span}\{\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-1\\
-1\\
1\end{array}\right]\}$.

But I can not get the final result of (b).

Comment: Are you sure you wrote $(b)$ correctly?

Comment: Also, why in (b) do you take $\,A^t\,$ and not $\,A\,$??

Comment: uh, this problem occurred twice in past qualifying exams. I think if it was wrong, it would not occur in the second time. If you think (b) is wrong, can you give us a counter example?

Comment: If I took $A$ instead of $A^{T}$, it also could not come out the result.

Comment: For $Ax = b$ to have solutions, we must have $b$ perpendicular to all vectors in the null space of $A^T$. This requires that for all $w$ in the null space of $A^T$, that we have $<w,b> = 0$. Doing that calculation yields $\beta = 5$, which is what you found in part $(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Any element in the kernel if of the form

$$x:=\begin{pmatrix}\frac k7+1\\\frac{5k}7-1\\k\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;w=\begin{pmatrix}\!\!-t\\\!\!-t\\t\end{pmatrix}$$  so their inner product is

$$x\cdot w=-\frac{kt}7-t-\frac{5kt}7+t+kt=0\iff \frac{6kt}7=kt\iff\;\;k=0\;\text{or}\;\;t=0\;$$

so unless you made some mistake while calculating the kernel , or there's a typo or some further condition somewhere, the claim's false.

Comment: I think $w$ can not be written as $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-t\\
-t\\
1\end{array}\right]$. It should be $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-t\\
-t\\
t\end{array}\right]$

Comment: You're right, @user81235. I corrected that typo and still there're some problems with the claim

Comment: This problem occurred in a qualifying exam. Do you know what is Fredholm's Aternative? Maybe it has some relationship with this problem.

Comment: Yup, I know what it is: a rather trivial fact from linear algebra. Anyway, I just did consider what you wrote.